# ASP.NET MVC Custom Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have a question about custom authorization in MVC.

I have a site that I want to limit access to certain pages, depending on their group membership.  Now I have seen tons of examples on how to do this if there is a single admin group and a single user group, for example, but not any examples for a third level.

For example, only users of a company can view orders for their own company (and each company has its own admins, etc).  These companies are stored in a DB.  So I have seen ways to do custom authorization, overriding the `AuthorizeCore` method on the `AuthorizeAttribute`, but I don't know how to access to the parameters passed into the controller to see if the user has access to the order (order id, for example).

Is this even the best place to do the check, or should this just be handled directly from the method of the controller?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The AuthorizationContext (parameter to OnAuthorize) provides access to the Controller, RouteData, HttpContext, etc.  You should be able to use these in a custom authorization filter to do what you want.  Below is a sample of code from a RoleOrOwnerAttribute derived from AuthorizeAttribute.

```
public override void OnAuthorization( AuthorizationContext filterContext )
{
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException( "filterContext" );
    }

    if (AuthorizeCore( filterContext.HttpContext )) // checks roles/users
    {
        SetCachePolicy( filterContext );
    }
    else if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // auth failed, redirect to login page
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
    // custom check for global role or ownership
    else if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole( "SuperUser" ) || IsOwner( filterContext ))
    {
        SetCachePolicy( filterContext );
    }
    else
    {
        ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
        viewData.Add( "Message", "You do not have sufficient privileges for this operation." );
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { MasterName = this.MasterName, ViewName = this.ViewName, ViewData = viewData };
    }

}

// helper method to determine ownership, uses factory to get data context,
// then check the specified route parameter (property on the attribute)
// corresponds to the id of the current user in the database.
private bool IsOwner( AuthorizationContext filterContext )
{
    using (IAuditableDataContextWrapper dc = this.ContextFactory.GetDataContextWrapper())
    {
        int id = -1;
        if (filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey( this.RouteParameter ))
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32( filterContext.RouteData.Values[this.RouteParameter] );
        }

        string userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        return dc.Table<Participant>().Where( p => p.UserName == userName && p.ParticipantID == id ).Any();
    }
}


protected void SetCachePolicy( AuthorizationContext filterContext )
{
    // ** IMPORTANT **
    // Since we're performing authorization at the action level, the authorization code runs
    // after the output caching module. In the worst case this could allow an authorized user
    // to cause the page to be cached, then an unauthorized user would later be served the
    // cached page. We work around this by telling proxies not to cache the sensitive page,
    // then we hook our custom authorization code into the caching mechanism so that we have
    // the final say on whether a page should be served from the cache.
    HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
    cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge( new TimeSpan( 0 ) );
    cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback( CacheValidateHandler, null /* data */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  What is the SetCachePolicy method?

Comment: I refactored the code from AuthorizeFilter that sets the caching policy for the page so that unauthorized users don't get the page served from cache.  I'll add that snippet.

Comment: In the SetCachePolicy, wouldn't it be a good idea to point at a CacheValidateHandler that expects the "original" AuthorizationContext to ensure the owner-check is re-evaluated before allowing cached responses?

Comment: @IDisposable - it inherits the behavior of the AuthorizeAttribute so it will only return cached responses if you are allowed as a user or in a role.  If you get access via your association, you won't ever get a cached response.  It could probably be more intelligent about that, but the primary users of authorization-protected pages are the admins.  I'll see what I can work up to allow cached responses for people who get access via "ownership."

Comment: @IDisposable - also, it's important not to use context from the previous request (since that one was authorized).  We need to reauthorize this request using the same mechanism, but the new request data.

Comment: @JNappi I create a FakeController (deriving from Controller), then a ControllerContext for that with suitable mocks for HttpContext, the current user (WindowsPrincipal), and HttpCachePolicyBase.  You can easily mock an ActionDescriptor. With the ActionDescriptor and the ControllerContext (with attendant mocks), you can create an AuthorizationContext to pass to OnAuthorization.  After calling just assure that your expectations are met and any changes to the context have been made.

Comment: Thanks for this answer I think it's pointed me in the right direction.  I've been trying to come up with my own version but I can't figure out where to get access to this.RouteParameter.  Is that something you added?

Comment: @NullReference - yes, it's a property on the attribute that allows you to specify the name of the parameter to inspect.

Answer (score 2):

If the authorization is really that dynamic, I would handle it in the controller. I have one action where I do this - you can return a HttpUnauthorizedResult to redirect to the login page or you can show a custom error in your view.

I don't the default redirect to the login page when somebody is already logged in, but not in the correct role. That's very confusing for the user.

Comment: You could do the same in an attribute, which can be easily applied via decoration on other methods that need it.

Comment: Yes, but you have to query the model anyway in the controller (usually). If you do it in the attribute, you have to query the model twice unless you have a clever caching mechanism

Answer (score 1):

My answer isn't great, because it kills unit testing, but I'm pulling values from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session`. The singleton is available throughout the project. By saving the current user in session, you can get to it from anywhere, including utility classes like `AuthorizeAttribute`.

I'd love to see a unit-testable solution, though.